# How to printout the URL that RestAssured trying to connect with to the web service?

Tags: java, rest-assured

This is very basic and simple question regarding Rest-assured framework. I have been trying to connect to weather webservice api using some param. But i kept getting connection refused. I could not find out what actually the URL that rest-assured trying to connect with.

```
given().
        param("APPID","xxxxxx").
        param("q","London").
    get(EndPoint.GET_ENDPOINT).
        then().
            statusCode(200).
                log().everything();
```

Getting this: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

I would like to print out the connection URL in my console. Do you have any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RestAssured` stores all the pieces of the URL it will construct as static variables.

```
System.out.println(RestAssured.baseURI + ":" + RestAssured.port + RestAssured.basePath + EndPoint.GET_ENDPOINT);
```

I don't know of a method that will combine them already, though I think it would be a reasonable feature request for a static method, or possibly on `RequestSpecification`.

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 10):

Move the `.log().all()` part to the `.given()̀  part, it should print it out to the console:

```
given().log().all()
  .param(…)…
```

Comment: This can be chained right after the contentType, as in ...contentType("application/JSON").given().log().all().get("api/v2/some/endpoint")...